# :last-child is not working

Tags: html, css-selectors

This is my first post here, so please tell me, if I'm doing something wrong.
I have a problem with the following code:

That's my HTML:

```
            <div class="sideSection">
            <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="mainContainer">
            <div class="articleHeader">
            <h3>Sapien lorem tempus</h3>
            <h4>Pharetra sed bibendum lorem</h4>
            </div>
            <p>Nunc cursus quam vitae ipsum viverra luctus. Nam nullam feugiat massa lacinia lectus vitae. Sed eu turpis at adipiscing.</p>
            <div class="sidebarBox">
            <img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="ernster Blick">
            <div class="sidebarBoxText">
            <a href="#">Cursus quam vitae</a>
            <p>Nunc cursus quam vitae ipsum viverra luctus sapien.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarBox">
            <img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="Straße">
            <div class="sidebarBoxText">
            <a href="#">Etiam at orci ut nibh</a>
            <p>Nunc cursus quam vitae ipsum viverra luctus sapien.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarBox">
            <img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt="telefonierender Blick">
            <div class="sidebarBoxText">
            <a href="#">Mauris non tellus</a>
            <p>Nunc cursus quam vitae ipsum viverra luctus sapien.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarBox">
            <img src="images/pic07.jpg" alt="Skyscraper">
            <div class="sidebarBoxText">
            <a href="#">Duis id ipsum</a>
            <p>Nunc cursus quam vitae ipsum viverra luctus sapien.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="moreInfoButton"><a href="#">More Info</a></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.sideSection .sidebar,
.sideSection .sidebar .sidebarBox {
float: left;
}
.sideSection .sidebar .sidebarBox {
padding: 25px 0px 20px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #ccc;
}
.sideSection .sidebar .sidebarBox:last-child {
border: none;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do, is to remove the border from the last "sidebarBox" class.
This isn't quite working out yet, because the code isn't affecting the border at all. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, and I hope that someone can help me here, as it is for work :S

EDIT: Okay, as far as I figured it out by now, it's a problem with the s.
When I use "".sidebarBox:nth-child(6)"" it works just fine..
Does the ":last-child" attribute actually count all s that I used in that section?

Comment: Your HTML code as shown does not contain a single `section` or `aside` element … Please create a [mcve], that actually reflects the problem.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean to put them in there.. They are not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-child` only matches the actual last child of the parent div.

You have the `.moreinfoButton` following it. If you can move the `button` to outside the `.mainContainer`, it will work as you expect it

Answer (score 1):

The `:last-child` selector applies to the last element inside a parent div. In your case the parent div is `.mainContainer` and its last child is `.moreInfoButton` and not `.sidebarBox`.

I would recommend you to add `last` class to the sidebarBox you want to modify, i.e. 
`<div class="sidebarBox last">`

and the corrspondent css code is

`.sideSection .sidebar .sidebarBox.last {
   border: none;
}`

Or another way to handle it is to wrap all your `.sidebarBox` elements in one parent `<div>`. Then you would be able to use `:last-child` selector.